# Find values for boundary condition for which ODE has a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$y'(t)=y(t)\\
y(0)=1\\
y(a)=a+2$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to determine the values for $a$ where a solution to this ODE can be found.

It seems quite simple, the solution is given by

$y(t)=c_1\exp(t)$ and therefore,
$y(0)=c_1=1$ and $y(a)=c_1\exp(a)=a+2$ so it follows that we must have
$a+2=e^{a}$ which is don't know how to solve. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: You have a _first_ order DE with _two_ conditions? Or are you just trying to find an $a$ such that $y(a) = a+2$?

Comment: Yes, but naturally for this to be solvable, the value $a$ has to satisfy both of them, so that they are effectively just one. At least this is what I think the exercise should show.

Comment: $y(0) = 1$ doesn't satisfy $y(a) = a+2$

Comment: Make a plot of the two functions $f_1(a) = e^a$ and  $f_2(a) = 2+a$ and look for the intersections. You will find two solutions $a_1 \simeq  1.14619$ and $a_2 \simeq  -1.84141$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you did not make a mistake.
The ODE $y'(t)=y(t)$ with initial condition $y(0)=1$ has a unique solution, namely $y(t)=e^t$. The equation $e^a=a+2$ has exactly two solutions, one positive and one negative, but it is probably impossible to "solve" it other than in a numerical way. You can easily prove that a solution exists (for example, draw the graphs), e.g., by noting that the function $f(a)=a+2-e^a$ satisfies $f(0)=1$, $\lim_{a\to\infty}f(a)=-\infty$ and $f'(a)=1-e^a\leq 0$, so by the intermediate value theorem there exists a solution to $f(a)=0$, and since $f$ is decreasing the positive solution is unique. Similar arguments can be used to show that there is also a unique negative solution. However, to actually compute the value of $a$ requires some numerical methods. Their values are approximatley $1.15$ and $-1.84$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^a=(a+2)\iff -e^{-2}=[-(a+2)]e^{-(a+2)}$$ can be solved by the Lambert-W function. As $-e^{-1}<-e^{-2}<0$ you get solutions on both real branches $a=-2-W_{-1}(-e^{-2})>-1$ and $a=-2-W_0(-e^{-2})<-1$.

```
In [20]: -2-lambertw(-np.exp(-2),k=-1)
Out[20]: (1.1461932206205825+0j)

In [21]: -2-lambertw(-np.exp(-2),k=0)
Out[21]: (-1.8414056604369606+0j)
```